# Enable Customer Portal and Enable Salesforce to Salesforce in Salesforce DX

Tags: customer-portal, salesforcedx, scratch-org, salesforce-to-salesforce

Hello fellow Salesforcers,

I am quite new to Salesforce DX and am currently trying to get the two features, "Enable Customer Portal" and "Enable Salesforce to Salesforce", to be enabled automatically during the scratch org creation.

As far as I read, the feature

> Communities

and the Org Preference

> NetworksEnabled

would provide this. But the newly created scratch orgs do not have these features enabled.

This is the JSON, I am currently using:

```
{
  "orgName": "default_scratch_org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Communities"],
  "orgPreferences": {
    "enabled": [
      "NetworksEnabled"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there anyone to have encountered this issue as well and could help me?

Thanks a lot in advance

Jörn

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Please let me know if you figured how to enable portal in a new scratch org